# Keeping client side in sync with server side - state management and http requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building shopping cart where some data between components needs to be shared - I build some kind of simple State management to keep from using Vuex which is pretty hard to understand, and It works.

The State management works in this way:

1.First of I create separated store/state file which is vanilla js (I'm using lodash)

```
import _    from    'lodash'

export default {

    data: {
        bag: []
    },

    add(item) {
        let found = _.find(this.data.bag, ['artnr', item.ID])

        if ( !found ) {
            this.data.bag.push({
                artnr: item.ID,
                name: item.post_name,
                qty: 1
            }) 
        } else {
            found.qty++
        }
    }

}
```

2.In my view component I import the State/Store file

```
import Store   from    '../stores/BagStore'
```

So then I create new data object property, called shared and assign data to Store.data

```
data() {
  return {
    item: [],
    shared: Store.data
  }
}
```

3.And at the end I have basic method that use method from state

```
methods: {
   addItem() {
      Store.add(this.item)
   }
}
```

And this thing work perfect, but I want to make a POST HTTP Request too, which would store data in database via API, and if user reload page the items he added should be here.

We built API in Laravel, that requure to pass 2 values (artnr and qty), I tried to make something like this

```
methods: {
   addItem() {
      Store.add(this.item)
      BagService.create(this.shared)
         .then(shared => {
             this.$dispatch('itemWasAdded', shared.data)
         })
   }
}
```

But then I got error

> 422 (Unprocessable Entity) The fields artnr and qty are required

Any idea, or better approach are welcome.Thanks.

Comment: Instead of storing this data on the server, I rather would do that local with a cookie. Then you just load your cookie, and get the items from the database. Unless you definitely really want to store them on the server site of course.

Comment: The message indicates that you don't send the right information to the server. The article number and quantity is missing or wrong. Check the content of your  POST request your sending in your dev console of the browser (usually F12)

Comment: @HerrDerb unfortunately cookies are not option in my case.
I know what message indicates, but can't figure out why

Comment: So what's the content of your POST request, which you're actually sending?

Comment: @HerrDerb check out first code snnipet.


`import _    from    'lodash'

export default {

    data: {
        bag: []
    },

    add(item) {
        let found = _.find(this.data.bag, ['artnr', item.ID])

        if ( !found ) {
            this.data.bag.push({
                artnr: item.ID,
                name: item.post_name,
                qty: 1
            }) 
        } else {
            found.qty++
        }
    }

}`

Comment: I'm not talking about the code, I'm talking about what gets sent to the server.
Again, press F12 in your browser to open the dev console, add a item to your basket and check what http post request was sent, and what its content was.

Comment: @HerrDerb as I mention, I got error so notning is send.

422 (Unprocessable Entity) The fields artnr and qty are required

Comment: `HTTP Status Code 422: The server understands the content type of the request entity`
Your requests was sent to the server, but it did not contain what the server is expecting, that's why you got this answer from the server. If you are not willing to check the faulty payload your are currently sending with your POST request, I'm not able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just log the contents you are sending to the server. It looks like it's `this.shared`. You'll see it's not the content you expect it to be. The server is likely expecting an item, and you're sending an array of items.

Comment: Thanks for reply.You are right, console.log return the array of objects, so I just should try with passing object ?

Comment: I'm wonder now, how to pass now each object from this.shared to the server, any idea ? Thanks.